# Javafx Tooltip blinks when is too big

Tags: java, javafx

I want to display a small image and display the image in the original size when the small is hover.

[image: Gif]

I need a tooltip because the image in the original size could not fit the window.

Executable code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String bigImageUrl = "https://cdn.lynda.com/course/184457/184457-636806635954727169-16x9.jpg";
        String smallImageUrl = "https://assets.exercism.io/tracks/java-bordered-turquoise.png";

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(loadTooltipWithImage(smallImageUrl));
        root.getChildren().add(loadTooltipWithImage(bigImageUrl));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Label loadTooltipWithImage(String url) {
        ImageView bigImage = new ImageView(new Image(url));
        ImageView smallImage = new ImageView(new Image(url));
        smallImage.setFitHeight(100.0);
        smallImage.setFitWidth(100.0);

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setGraphic(smallImage);

        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.setGraphic(bigImage);
        label.setTooltip(tooltip);
        return label;
    }
}
```

A tooltip displays an image when a node is hover, but when image is too big the node cannot be hovered by the mouse:

1. The node is hover
2. The tooltip displays image
3. The node is not hover
4. The tooltip does not display
5. Go to step 1

What I tried:

- Set mouse transparent to true on the tooltip, but I could not
- Use a pane instead of tooltip, but the window (stage) is too small for the image
- Set the mouse filters, but they do not help me

Comment: If a user wants to see the full size image, a tooltip won’t be especially useful.  Consider an alternative, like “click to zoom” which would show a dialog with an ImageView in a ScrollPane.  A more useful tooltip might be text like “Showing at original size” or “Showing at 45% of original size”.